# Wiener Measure of Open subsets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, wiener-measure

Let $C(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of continuous functions from the $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, let C_0 denote the linear subspace consisting only of those functions that take the value zero at the infimum of the set $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\nu$ denote the classical Wiener measure on $C_0$.

Is it true that for any non-empty open subset $U$ of $C(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$ and for any non-empty open subset $V$ of $C_0$ that

- $\nu^n\times\nu(U)>0$ (where $\nu^n$ is the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$),
- $\nu(V)>0$?

It seems intuitive to me, since $\nu$ is Gaussian on finite-dimensional projections but I can't seem to prove it.

Comment: Did mean by $\nu^n \times \nu$ the tensor product $\nu^n \otimes \nu$. If this is true, we consider the tensorised space $\mathbb R^n \otimes C_0 $ endowed with the canonical $\sigma$-algebra of event of the form $A\otimes F$ where $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $F\subseteq C_0$.

Comment: I mean the product measure, as in this Wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Wiener_space#Classical_Wiener_measure